Composing binary quadratic forms with different discriminants
Gauss' notion composition of binary quadratic forms is general enough to work for forms with different discriminants, but from what I've been able to find, most people since then have focused on the special case where the discriminants are the same and have alternate (and in most cases, simpler) description of the operation.
I wasn't able to understand the composition of forms with unequal discriminant very well (from the presentation in Disquistiones Arithmeticae), is there a simpler exposition in some other work that someone could point me to?
In particular, is there a generalization of Dirichlet composition (along with some closed form formulae) that can be used to compose two binary quadratic forms of different discriminants? Or perhaps, some way to use/extend Bhargava's cubes to capture different discriminants?

well, you can do this if the ratio of the two discriminants is a rational square. This is section 7.3 in Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms.

Trifkovic does this with Bhargava cubes; from what I can see the discriminants must still be in the same squareclass

@WillJagy I think these are good starting points for me to go off of, thanks! As a side note, composition is not well-defined when the discriminants are not of the form $Dn^2$ and $Dn'^2$?

That does seem to be the case in Gauss as well
